# MySQL data prompt in UK 'dd-mm-yyyy'

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I am new to MySQL and can't seem to find a answer to convert a date prompt to UK date. Where the user can enter the date in the format of 'dd-mm-yyyy'.
The actual field is in unixtimestamp as well. What I am trying to do is have the user filter between 2 date period example.

where datefield between (unixtimestamp) and (unixtimestamp)

(the date entered will have to be in the format 'dd-mm-yyyy'

If anyone can shed some light, it will be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `str_to_date`. The `STR_TO_DATE()` converts the str string into a date value based on the fmt format string.

```
between str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y') and str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: How would I do that on SSRS if you know?

Comment: select FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"%d/%m/%y"), dateadded, FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"dd/mm/yy") 
from purchase_orders 
where dateadded between str_to_date("01/11/15",'%d/%m/%Y') and str_to_date("08/11/15",'%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: try this query @abs786123

Comment: Hi Rahautos, tried that still no rows returned. I was getting the same from before, any ideas?

Comment: # FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"%d/%m/%y"), dateadded, FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"dd/mm/yy")
'03/09/14', '1409749961', 'dd/mm/yy'
'03/09/14', '1409750205', 'dd/mm/yy'
'03/09/14', '1409750808', 'dd/mm/yy'
'03/09/14', '1409750996', 'dd/mm/yy'
'03/09/14', '1409751501', 'dd/mm/yy'
'03/09/14', '1409751848', 'dd/mm/yy'
'08/09/14', '1410166351', 'dd/mm/yy'

Comment: above is the actual results of the raw data in the table

Comment: column **dateadded** is varchar type   @abs786123

Comment: does that mean I would have to to_date somehow to get the results?

Comment: purchase_order_id bigint(20) NO PRI  
job_id bigint(20) YES   
purchase_order_no int(11) NO MUL  auto_increment
purchase_order_group enum('purchase_order','bill_of_materials','subcontractor') YES   
pad_no varchar(200) NO MUL  
purchase_order_type varchar(20) NO MUL main 
purchase_date varchar(15) NO MUL  
branch_id bigint(20) YES   
dateadded varchar(15) NO MUL

Comment: select FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"%d/%m/%y"), dateadded, FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"dd/mm/yy") from purchase_orders 
where str_to_date(dateadded,'%d/%m/%Y') between str_to_date("01/11/15",'%d/%m/%Y') and str_to_date("08/11/15",'%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: try this query @abs786123

Comment: could it be because the field is actually a unixtime stamp?

Comment: Thank you Rahautos, it is sorted now :)

Comment: answer was: select FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"%d/%m/%y"), dateadded, FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"dd/mm/yy") 
 from purchase_orders 
 where str_to_date(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded, "%d/%m/%Y"),'%d/%m/%Y') 
 between str_to_date("01/08/15",'%d/%m/%Y') and str_to_date("08/11/15",'%d/%m/%Y')

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a function in your application to convert from the UK format `dd-mm-yyyy` to the mysql format `yyyy-mm-dd`, this way will send the parameters in the correct format.

Comment: Hiya, just tried this:

    select FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"%d/%m/%y"), dateadded, FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"dd/mm/yy") from purchase_orders where dateadded between str_to_date("01/11/15",'%d-%m-%Y') and str_to_date("08/11/15",'%d-%m-%Y')

but it doesn't bring back any results. I am tried different combination of date and '-' between. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: @abs786123 Try this: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateadded, '%d/%m/%y'), dateadded FROM purchase_orders WHERE dateadded between str_to_date('01/11/15', '%d/%m/%y') and str_to_date('08/11/15', '%d/%m/%y')`. You're using %Y instead of %y. If you use %Y you have to provide four digits year like 1991, 2000, 2010 but you're using two digits, so you have to use %y

Answer (score 0):

```
 select FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"%d/%m/%y"), dateadded, FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded,"dd/mm/yy") 
 from purchase_orders 
 where str_to_date(FROM_UNIXTIME(dateadded, "%d/%m/%Y"),'%d/%m/%Y') 
 between str_to_date("01/08/15",'%d/%m/%Y') and str_to_date("08/11/15",'%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Explain your answer. It will help the OP understand better.